# Add Children to element of type Page created in code behind Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, uielement

I can create a new element of type `Page` in code behind, but I want to add children elements of type `UIElement` as I would to a `Grid` like: `myGrid.Children.Add(myUIElement);`
I don't have the `Children` property and setting the `Content` property does not work.
How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE:**
This is what I have so far, but does not work:

```
Page myNewPage = new Page();
Grid myGrid = new Grid();
TextBlock myText = new TextBlock();
myText.Text = "I am a TextBlock!";
myGrid.Children.Add(myText);
myNewPage.Content = myGrid;

Frame.Navigate(myNewPage.GetType());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Page` can host a single `UIElement` in its `Content` property. To add several children, you have to do it like you would do it in XAML: add a panel that can contain and layout several children and add your elements to that panel.

In your question you talk about a grid called `myGrid`. You could add and layout your items in `myGrid` and then set `myGrid` as `yourPage.Content`.

Your code correctly builds the page. The problem with your code is that your `Frame` is navigating to a new instance of `Page` that is not the one that you created. `Frame` creates a new instance of the **type** that you pass as a parameter.

If you want to create a page fully in code, you can simply create class that extends `Page` and build the page in its constructor:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        this.BuildPage();
    }

    private void BuildPage()
    {
        var panel = new StackPanel();
        panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "Hello" });
        panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "World" });

        this.Content = panel;
    }
}
```

That's, after all, what the `InitializeComponent` method does in pages created in XAML.

Comment: You mean doing something like: `Grid newGrid = new Grid(); myPage.Content = newGrid; newGrid.Children.Add(myUIElement);`? If so, this does not work, if not, could you please provide an example?

Comment: you should provide a more complete example of what you are doing to get a better idea from context of what may be going wrong

Comment: I've added what I ended up with so far.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain why your code does not work. The problem is not in the page creation, but in the navigation.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But if I create a new `Page.xaml` item in my project I don't have this problem, even though I define `typeof` and not the exact `Page.xaml`. How could I set my new Page in code behind to have the content I set by default?

Comment: When you create `Page.xaml` you are not creating an instance of the page, you are creating the **definition** of the `Page` class.

Comment: Nice, that was what I was looking for. However, when I try to navigate to the new MyPage I get an exception `Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Foundation'.` Couldn't find an answer for that...

Comment: That's another problem that would deserve another question.